# Need to move space out of extended partition

Tags: gparted, lvm, partitioning

So i'm trying to move 30 gigs out of the extended partition and into sda2. Any idea how i would that? I would prefer using gparted to do this but i can use command line if needed.
[image: Partition layout]

Comment: sda2 is the extended partition, and already contains the 30G unallocated -- what are you trying to do?

Comment: Move the free space out of the extended partition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have three primary partitions (including the extended, you can just shrink the extended (making sure its end is at or beyond the end of sda5), and make one new partition at location of the unallocated space.  Best to use a partitioning tool in which you can see the exact partition start/end in sectors, to avoid overlap.  The new partition will probably be given a number like sda2, but the numbers do not have to be in order.